# NotifyItemRemoved throws an exception

Tags: android, exception, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I have this kind of problem. I have a simple app for wallpapers. 
 I am getting wallpapers from `API`, there is a `Tab` called `Category` in which I have `Sections` I would like to hide few of that `Sections` inside `Category` `Tab`.

In the best scenario my backend developer have to hide or remove it from backend but as he is not available now. I have decided to do it myself.

So, in `RecyclerView` for `Category` `Tab` in `onBindViewHolder` I am checking if the title is equal the one that I want to be deleted I am calling `removeAt` (you can see that part below):

```
            if (categoryTitle.equals("Hot")) {
                list.removeAt(holder.layoutPosition)
            }
```

I need this to be called whenever the `Category` `Tab` shows so the user will not be able to see that `Category` `Section`. But it doesn't update it because I have to call this two methods as well:

```
    if (categoryTitle.equals("Hot")) {
                    list.removeAt(holder.layoutPosition)
    notifyItemRemoved(holder.layoutPosition)
    notifyItemRangeChanged(holder.layoutPosition, list.size)

}
```

but while call them I got en error saying

*"Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling . . ."*

Here is the question.
Where I have to call it to avoid the error ?

(link of my app: 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.backpaper)

(please do not suggest to use timer or delay or something similar `(-_-)` )

Update:

```
            override fun onResponse(categories: Categories) {

                categories.categories!!.removeAt(5)
                categories.categories!!.removeAt(1)

                adapter = RecyclerViewAdapterC(categories.categories!!)}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Do not remove item in `onBindViewHolder()`** It will throw exception because item is not added yet . Exception will be as.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling

You should remove the item from dataset before adding them to adapter .

```
 if (!categoryTitle.equals("Hot")) {
           // Add item else do not add item 
     }
```

After filtering the list dataset then set adapter with filtered list .

below is an example .

```
 ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList();
    for(String cat : categories.categories){
     if (!categoryTitle.equals("Hot")) {
      list.add(cat);
       }
    }
    adapter = RecyclerViewAdapterC(list)
```

Comment: so on onResponse part here is my code
                               adapter = RecyclerViewAdapterC(categories.categories!!).

Comment: you need to filter `categories.categories` before setting adapter . As i said above . Got it ?

Comment: So I have to firstly now the position of item than be able to remove it from the initial dataset. but how I can know the position ?

Comment: yes I did it it wokred but I am manually giving the position of an item

Comment: Why manually .Just use a for loop to traverse and remove the desired one .

Comment: I have updated my question. It works perfectly in this way.

Comment: Why `removeAt(5)`? just check the condition `if (!categoryTitle.equals("Hot"))` and remove . You can use what i have just stated in answer.

Comment: categoryTitle I have to get like this list[position].getName()

Comment: I think the code That I share with is not enough for you to understand my architecture.

Comment: If you want I can share with my repository

Comment: This does not matter . The thing matter is you have to provide a pre filtered list . It does not matter weather you are using `ArrayList` or `Array` or any other . Just loop through the list and remove which are `equal(hot)` . And if you do no need `hot` anyway anywhere in app later then just do not add it at all .then problem will be solved .

Comment: solved it 
class Categories {
    @SerializedName("categories")
    @Expose
    var categories: ArrayList<Category>? = null
}

the problem was that my getcategorytitle was nested inside other object